# Hard disk broken after having to rescue files with dd_rescue?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

Normally, a hard disk should take care of bad blocks by marking them unsuable. If that isn't any more the case with a hard disk, is it still possible to do keep track of those bad block with some kernel module or other daemon process in Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Generally bad blocks on a disk are transparently remapped by the disk itself, and the OS usually has no way to see, access, or even recognize those bad blocks.  All modern OS's rely on the disk to handle bad blocks, and do not support any sort of block remapping.

If you have a disk that isn't remapping bad blocks, or is somehow exposing them to the OS, then you have a disk that is failing, and needs to be replaced.  Continuing to use it **will** result in data loss.

Answer (score 0):

If 'e2fsck -c' doesn't work you're out of luck.
But if your hard disk is so bad that the list of bad blocks is full you should replace it immediately.